# Using FileStream with dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to write a simple application that reads then writes a csv file, this is a good occasion to start writing in .net core.

I'm already stuck with the reading part.

I'm using CsvHelper Nuget package.

I tried to use it like before :

```
var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(FilePath));
```

But it seems that StreamReader doesn't access file path anymore.

I then tried with :

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileAccess.Read))
    {

    }
```

But the error is now that it cannot convert FilePath from String to Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle

I did not find much information on this simple topic.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found it, it was simply:

```
new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(FilePath))
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, then I realized it works like this:

```
new FileStream(filePathString,  FileMode.Open)
```

use `FileMode` not `FileAccess`